# Reconcile *differences* rather than different *things*

Tags: word-usage

With exceptions, *reconciliation* occurs between disparate *things*.  It seems to me that referring to the *differences* between those things as being reconciled or reconcilable (or not) is a mis-use of the words *reconcile* and *reconcilable*.  Yet, the term *irreconcilable* *differences* is common place.  Is this just one of those mis-uses that have become formally acceptable, or am I totally off-base in assuming that it seems wrong?

Comment: Two people may very well have "differences" with regard to a single "thing".  How to spend money, how to deal with children, whether to mow the lawn north-south or east-west.

Comment: It might help if you could explain why do you think that "referring to the differences between those things as being reconciled or reconcilable (or not) is a mis-use of the words reconcile and reconcilable."

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow your premise.

Comment: Every person is different from every other person. The difference between persons is not a reason to be in disharmony. If persons become separated by disharmony it is the persons who need to be reconciled one to another, not their differences.

Comment: In keeping with Nigel's example, my default assumption is that reconciliation applies to things that have differences between them (e.g., people or ideas) rather than the differences themselves.

Comment: Words mean what they are used to mean, not what somebody thinks they ought to mean, or what logic says they should mean.

Answer (score 0):

> different things

**Different** used as an *adjective modifier* for the *noun*, ***things***. "What things?" "**Different** things."

> irreconcilable differences

**Differences** used as a *noun*, making **differences** the *thing* in question. "What **differences**?" "Their irreconcilable **differences**."

**Differences** is plural, and means **disparate** ***things***.

> **differences** (*plural noun*):
>   1...*synonyms*: ...**disparity**...

Comment: I guess that the reason this sounds off to me is that I assume that reconciliation applies to things that have differences between them (e.g., people or ideas) rather than the differences themselves.

Comment: For example, one may reconcile the two databases by delving into the provenances of the data and adjudicating the data disparities.  One may reconcile the two visions by explaining apparent differences.